# Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.util.List<logica.Persona>

Tags: java, typeerror

---

Hola, me tira el error del titulo, nose ni que hacer ni como resolverlo la verdad a alguien se le ocurre que puede ser lo que lo genera y como arreglarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: parece que tu metodo traerPersona es un metodo void y no un return

Comment: Hola @leon, parece que tienes un problema de incompatibilidad en tu código, sería bueno que intentaras añadir a la pregunta una muestra de tu código, así los demás podrían emular el problema que tienes eso también es lo que se recomienda en este artículo [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)